# how to open UIViewController when i click RowSelected from UITableViewSource

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i want open viewcontroller  when i click  RowSelected from UITableViewSource

i use this code when i open UIViewController

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

```
MainStudUn controller =this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MainStudUn") as MainStudUn; 
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
```

but i  have issue when used this code from UITableViewSource

```
class EmployeesTVS : UITableViewSource
{
    List<Employee> employees;

    public EmployeesTVS(List<Employee> employees)
    {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = (EmployeeCell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell("Cell_id", indexPath);
        var employee = employees[indexPath.Row];
        cell.updatecell(employee);
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return employees.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var SelectName = employees[indexPath.Row];

        Globals.AskX = SelectName.Fullname;
        Globals.AnswerX = SelectName.Department;

        //OpnWerd();
        //MainStudUn controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MainStudUn") as MainStudUn;
        //this.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set the ViewController itself as parameter in the initializing constructor of the dataSource.**

in ViewController

```
this.TableView.Source = new EmployeesTVS(tableItems, this);
```

in dataSource

```
AskStud owner; //this is your VC class not ViewController,it's just a sample.
public EmployeesTVS(List<Employee> employees, AskStud  owner)
{
    this.employees = employees;
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

Usage:

```
MainStudUn controller =this.owner.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MainStudUn") as MainStudUn; 
//OR 
//UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryBoardName", null);
//MainStudUn controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("MainStudUn") as MainStudUn;

this.owner.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
```

Comment: Error CS1061 'EmployeesTVS' does not contain a definition for 'Storyboard' and no extension method 'Storyboard' accepting a first argument of type 'EmployeesTVS' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: listVStud.Source = new EmployeesTVS(employees, this);
                listVStud.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
                listVStud.EstimatedRowHeight = 100F;
                listVStud.ReloadData();

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'TrainingIOS.AskStud' to 'TrainingIOS.ViewController' TrainingIOS D:\TrainingIOS\TrainingIOS\AskStud.cs 67

Comment: @Eng.Ahmed  e......ViewController is the first VC class ...  See my updated answer..

Comment: Sorry Issue is here  :  listVStud.Source = new EmployeesTVS(employees, this);
 cannot convert from 'TrainingIOS.AskStud' to 'TrainingIOS.ViewController'

Comment: @Eng.Ahmed , did you modify the initializing constructor of the dataSource ？` public EmployeesTVS(List<Employee> employees, AskStud  owner)`

Comment: yes ,    class EmployeesTVS : UITableViewSource
    {
          List<Employee> employees;

        ViewController owner;
        public EmployeesTVS(List<Employee> employees, ViewController owner)
        {
            this.employees = employees;
            this.owner = owner;
        }